# storing records in mysql db in sorting order of date

Tags: mysql

I want to store some records in mysql database. records have a date column. i want to store them in sorting order of that date column.

For example, record having date **27/sep/2011**  get stored *as first row* on the top of record having date **26/sep/2011** as:

id_1,name_1,27/sep/2011
id_2,name_2,26/sep/2011

if new records come on future dates they would get inserted on the top.

I DONT want to order them while using select by using order by desc .
i want they get inserted into db directly in sorted order.

how to do this???

thanks...

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this ?

Comment: Good heavens, insert them and create an index. Ordering them on retrieval.

Comment: this is not how databases work. you store data in it, you dont order them in the database, you order and filter your resultsets based on your needs.

Comment: Why Why?? but Why do you want this?

Comment: @brightness - its good practive on Stackoverflow to accept an answer - you will get more of a response to future questions if you can accept an answer for every question.

Comment: I doubt this is the intention of the person asking this question, but there is an actual reason to do this; to reduce the amount of reads made to the disk (by basically defragmenting the table). There is a mechanism to do it in pgsql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html.

Answer (score 3):

I am always surprised when people want to determine physical order of storing records. 
Basically, it's a terrible idea for multiple reasons.

1) How the record is physically stored should not be of your concern.

2) How the record is presented should be of your concern. That's why we have ORDER BY built in.

3) Determining physical storage should be done by experts in the field, since it has performance implications - which is a topic in its own and I won't go into details.

Basically, worry about getting the data out in the sorted order, not getting it in in the sorted order.

Reason why it's a bad idea is because you'll be tampering with the primary key which is never, ever a good idea. On top of that, you'll have to reorder the records every time you insert something. Just don't reinvent hot water.

Comment: Wouldn't periodically re ordering a data base with say 20 000 000 million values not be more efficient than reordering them on every single request? The reordering process seems to be the bottle neck of my entire system right now. If i do it in the client it hangs up for 4-7 seconds. I have yet to try doing it on the server but, with the way the client handles it i don't have high hopes.

Comment: It wouldn't. You have to retrieve 20m values (from disk usually), then MySQL has to store that somewhere (if your RAM is insufficient, it goes to disk again). Then it has to sort that based on your desired condition and write it back to disk. The alternative is that you let MySQL choose the optimal way to save it (it physically orders it by PK), then you retrieve what you need (you definitely won't need 20 m records) - this is quick because you will use some conditions - and then you sort that in the way you need it. It's the same operation, but on a smaller scale.

Comment: I see this has a valid question, if this was a usecase for timeseries data or data on to which you always query in ranges of the specified column then storing this way makes sense which completely eliminates the need to sort, even to do pagination on the result set we have to load all data paginate then return the appropiate page everytime you query

Comment: @Laukik the question, which was asked 11 years ago, mentions **MySQL** and it even contains tag `mysql`. time series != mysql, which brings up the question - why comment if you don't read fully?

Comment: You are correct this may not be for timeseries, but something like that maybe logging i mentioned the usecase of range queries with an "Or" in my comment, yes the question was 11 years ago so what learning doesnt stop..

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding another table - inserting all of the records into that table (the current and the new ones) then doing and insert as follows :

```
INSERT into newtable
select * from temptable
order by temptable.date
```

Why do you need to do this ? why not just use orderby on the query ?

As pointed out in the comments below - you would need to truncate the newtable each time

Comment: You also need to delete entries in this `newtable` table every time before new row needs to be inserted.

Comment: @GhazanfarMir - yes your right .... its a silly idea anyhow - I would always use OrderBy on the query ... just trying to point them in the right direction should they choose to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose where to insert your row.

Here's one possible solution: [MySQL syntax for inserting a new row in middle rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333623/mysql-syntax-for-inserting-a-new-row-in-middle-rows)